# AngularJS ngRoute not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm trying to use the ngRoute in my angularJS page, but I'm not able to load my content within ng-view.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="CSS/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<header>
    <a ng-href="#/add-new">Add new</a>
</header>
<div ng-view></div>
<footer>
    @Copyright 2017
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/add-new', {
        template: 'Some content'
    })
}]);
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

If I add otherwise condition on $routeProvider, it gets loaded. Please let me know what am I missing here so that the content within my $routeProvider.when gets loaded in my ng-view on markup. Thanks

Also not getting any console errors.

Comment: Try to add otherwise after your `.when()` like this: `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:'/add-new'});`

Comment: @FabioPicheli The content within 'when' is not getting loaded for me, thats my issue. In the request URL, if i access http://localhost:8080/index.htm#/add-new

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Mistalis Angular 1

Comment: Here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ommonyj5/).

Comment: @Mistalis I think im missing something wrt reference in my local... Even if i copy and run the working demo in my local, facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

JS:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "index.htm"
  })
  .when("/add-new", {
    templateUrl : "add.htm"
  })
 });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#!add-new">Red</a>
```

Comment: @Manju if you could create a plunkr with issue, then it would be easier to find solution

Comment: Changing / to ! in the href value did work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add this below line in your `HTML` page

```
<base href="/">
```

and change `ng-href` to `href`

**EDIT :**

> - `$location` in HTML5 mode requires a [`<base>`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase) tag to be present!
> - If you using `ng-href`, the you should pass `$scope` object

Comment: Right, but an explanation of *why* it is the solution may be useful for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have entry point for the app, so if you load your app and you are not going to specific url you will not see any results.

You can add otherwise({redirectTo:'/add-new'}) or go to #/add-new to see your page